# A simple question on predual in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra, **then $A^{*}=(A^{**})_{*}$?** Here, $(.)_{*}$ denotes the predual of $(.)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every von Neumann algebra $M$ has unique predual $M_*$. Second dual $A^{**}$ of $C^*$ algebra $A$ in fact is a von Neumann algebra which is called enveloping von Neumann algebra. For $M=A^{**}$ we have unique predual which is clearly (now) is $A^*$.

Comment: Sorry, my question is why $A^{*}=(A^{**})_{*}$. I only know that, for a von Neumann algebra M, $(M^{*})_{*}=M$.

Comment: You know it wrong, because the correct identity is $(M_*)^*=M$

Comment: Oh~yes, it is $(M_{*})^{*}=M$. But how to    conclude $A^{*}=(A^{**})_{*}$?

Comment: It is explained in my answer. What you do not understand in it?

Comment: If we regard $A^{**}$ as a von Neumann algebra, then , I suppose, we can conclude that $((A^{**})_{*})^{*}=A^{**}$ (from $(M_{*})^{*}=M$, M is an arbitrary von Neumann algebra). But does this imply $A^{*}=(A^{**})_{*}$?

Comment: $A^{**}$ is dual space. It has at least one predual $A^*$. May be $A^{**}$ have other preduals? No! Because $A^{**}$ is van Neumann algebra its predual is **UNIQUE**.